# Scala: How to shutdown executor if we don't know the execution time in future?

Tags: scala, future

Suppose I have a simple application

```
object FutureApp extends App {

  val executor = newFixedThreadPool(8)
  implicit val executionContext = fromExecutorService(executor)

  val start = currentTimeMillis()
  /*
   * In real application we don't know how long it could take to execute the
   * future body 
   */
  val f0: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(2700); 0 }
  val f1: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(5500); 1 }
  val f2: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(1500); 2 }

  val seq: Future[List[Int]] = Future.sequence(f0 :: f1 :: f2 :: Nil)

  seq onComplete {
    case Success(res) => println { "R:" + res          }
    case Failure(t)   => println { "R:" + t.getMessage }
  }
  /*
   * Instead of invoking the code below I want to shutdown the 
   * executor without specifying the biggest execution time (5500) 
   */
  if (!executionContext.awaitTermination(5500, MILLISECONDS)) {
    val end = currentTimeMillis()

    println { s"executionTime=${(end - start).toDouble / 1000}" }

    executionContext.shutdownNow()
  }

}
```

It executes the code in three future bodies (`body: =>T`). I want to combine the result of futures execution, and for that, I use `Future.sequence` function. There is only one issue I need to solve. I need to shutdown the executor with respect to biggest execution time, which I don't know. It could be 5 seconds or 10 minutes, etc.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why not `Future.sequence(....).onComplete{_ => executionContext.shutdownNow()}`?

Comment: Yeap, it is reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your simple case:

```
Future.sequence(....).onComplete{_ => executionContext.shutdownNow()}
```

But if you have number of cyclic dependent computation and you need to know when they are finished - you could use lattice abstraction. It is presented in "[Programming with Futures, Lattices, and Quiescence](http://event.scaladays.org/scaladays-berlin-2016#!#schedulePopupExtras-7613)" by @philippkhaller.

Comment: Since order of `onComplete` is arbitrary, you'd have to shutdown from the callback that prints the result or risk losing it. Or use `future.andThen`. Thanks for interesting link.